# How to apply K means in a mask of an image instead the whole one

Tags: opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to apply on OpenCV a K Means to a region of an image not squared or a rectangle. For example the source image is:

[image]

now I select a custom mask:

[image]

and apply K Means with K = 3:

[image]

Obviously without considering the bounds (white).

Instead, what I can do with OpenCV is K Means but considering the bounds:

[image]

And that messes out my final image because black is considered one colour.

Do you have any clue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If want to do it the right way, you probably have to adapt the openCV function (which might be easy since it is open source and probably just a single mask check before adding the colors to the clustering mechanic, but thats a guess).
If you want to fake you could try to copy the masked area to a image with background a color that doesnt appear in the image (best a maximum distance to occuring colors). then do a (k+1)-means operation. then ignore the cluster that represents the background color and cluster all the rest.

Comment: It is a good solution, but not working at some points on what I'm doing, sorry!! but it was very clever!

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty solution.

```
vector<Vec3b> points;
vector<Point> locations;
for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++) {
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++) {
        if ( (int)mask.at<unsigned char>(y,x) != 0 ) {
            points.push_back(src.at<Vec3b>(y,x));
            locations.push_back(Point(x,y));
        }
    }   
}
Mat kmeanPoints(points.size(), 3, CV_32F);
for( int y = 0; y < points.size(); y++ ) {
    for( int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
        kmeanPoints.at<float>(y, z) = points[y][z];
    }
}

Mat labels;
Mat centers;
kmeans(kmeanPoints, 4, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.1), 10, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
Mat final = Mat::zeros( src.size(), src.type() );
Vec3b tempColor;

for(int i = 0; i<locations.size(); i++) {
    int cluster_idx = labels.at<int>(i,0);
    tempColor[0] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 0);
    tempColor[1] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 1);
    tempColor[2] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 2);
    final.at<Vec3b>(locations[i]) = tempColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an input RGB image called `img`[(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDKvk.png) and a one-channel mask called `mask`[(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMaZ2.png), here is the **snippet to prepare your k-means computation** :

```
int nbClasses = 3;  // or whatever you want
cv::TermCriteria myCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER + cv::TermCriteria::EPS, 10, 1.0);
cv::Mat labels, centers, result;
img.convertTo(data, CV_32F);    
// reshape into 3 columns (one per channel, in BGR order) and as many rows as the total number of pixels in img
data = data.reshape(1, data.total());
```

If you want to apply a **normal k-means** (without mask) :

```
// apply k-means    
cv::kmeans(data, nbClasses, labels, myCriteria, 3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);

// reshape both to a single column of Vec3f pixels
centers = centers.reshape(3, centers.rows); 
data = data.reshape(3, data.rows);

// replace pixel values with their center value
cv::Vec3f *p = data.ptr<cv::Vec3f>();
for (size_t i = 0; i < data.rows; i++) 
{
    int center_id = labels.at<int>(i);
    p[i] = centers.at<cv::Vec3f>(center_id);
}

// back to 2D image
data = data.reshape(3, img.rows);

// optional conversion to uchar
data.convertTo(result, CV_8U);
```

The result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz3km.png).

But, if you want instead to apply a **masked k-means** :

```
int nbWhitePixels = cv::countNonZero(mask);
cv::Mat dataMasked = cv::Mat(nbWhitePixels, 3, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(0));
cv::Mat maskFlatten = mask.reshape(1, mask.total());
    
// filter data by the mask
int idx = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < mask.total(); k++)
{
    int val = maskFlatten.at<uchar>(k, 0);          
    if (val != 0)
    {
        float val0 = data.at<float>(k, 0);
        float val1 = data.at<float>(k, 1);
        float val2 = data.at<float>(k, 2);
        dataMasked.at<float>(idx,0) = val0;
        dataMasked.at<float>(idx,1) = val1;
        dataMasked.at<float>(idx,2) = val2;
        idx++;
    }
}

// apply k-means    
cv::kmeans(dataMasked, nbClasses, labels, myCriteria, 3, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);

// reshape to a single column of Vec3f pixels
centers = centers.reshape(3, centers.rows);  
dataMasked = dataMasked.reshape(3, dataMasked.rows);
data = data.reshape(3, data.rows);

// replace pixel values with their center value, only for pixels in mask
cv::Vec3f *p = data.ptr<cv::Vec3f>();
idx = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < data.rows; i++)
{
    if (maskFlatten.at<uchar>(i, 0) != 0)
    {
        int center_id = labels.at<int>(idx);
        p[i] = centers.at<cv::Vec3f>(center_id);
        idx++;
    }
    //else
    //    p[i] = cv::Vec3f(0, 0, 0);    
}

// back to 2d, and uchar
data = data.reshape(3, img.rows);
data.convertTo(result, CV_8U);
```

You will have now [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBHhO.png).

If you let commented the **else part**, you will keep initial pixels outside the mask, whereas if you uncomment it, you will convert them into black pixels, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2TGq.png).